# WP8 - How to know if there is app to open the file (extension)?

Tags: windows-phone-8, file-extension

In WP8, I'm opening a file (pdf) with the following method:

```
bool success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync (docfile);
```

but the method always returns 'true' (whether or not any app to open the file).

How can I check before making the asynchronous call to open the file, if there is certainly any app to open this kind of file (eg extension pdf)?

Comment: That type of information is not available in Windows Phone due to it's "locked-down" nature.  The only time you'll get a false result from `LaunchFileAsync` is if the file will never be allowed to launch (i.e. .exe, .js, etc...).  You can give the option of picking which app to use when launched with the `LauncherOptions.DisplayApplicationPicker` property.